# How to DRY up this code c#

Tags: c#

I am working on a c# application where you can select movies from a `combobox` and it displays the movie info and the actors that were in it in a `datagrid`, gets all the information from a MySql database. Now I've googled most of what I need to learn and implement it into my code. The blocks of code look massive and were wondering if there was any way to dry it up a bit, such as what variables can I reuse if any, etc.

```
//film select
var queryfilmsearch = "SELECT title, description, release_year, rental_rate, length, rating FROM film WHERE title LIKE + @value";
MySqlCommand cmdfilmsearch = new MySqlCommand(queryfilmsearch,  PubVar.connection);
cmdfilmsearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", comBoxFilm.Text);
MySqlDataAdapter adpfilmserach = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdfilmsearch);
DataSet dsfilmsearch = new DataSet();
adpfilmserach.Fill(dsfilmsearch);
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dsfilmsearch.Tables[0];

//actor from film select
var queryfilmactor = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM actor INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id INNER JOIN film ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id WHERE film.title LIKE + @value";
MySqlCommand cmdfilmactor = new MySqlCommand(queryfilmactor, PubVar.connection);
cmdfilmactor.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", comBoxFilm.Text);
MySqlDataAdapter adpfilmactor = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdfilmactor);
DataSet dsfilmactor = new DataSet();
adpfilmactor.Fill(dsfilmactor);
dataGridView2.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView2.DataSource = dsfilmactor.Tables[0];
```

It's basically the same code just different query and variable names

Comment: If you just want to minimize your code > create a function, replace key words and variables with local variables from the function and done Iguess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains working code which requires improvements. This question might be more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please read what's on topic on each SE portal before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a lot of boilerplate, but it doesn't have to be.

First off, you're using your connections wrong. They implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). You should take special care in handling them properly. This means that storing them as a variable is usually a bad idea. Open and close them as quickly as possible, and don't share them.

Second, you're using raw ADO.NET. While it's good to have an idea of how ADO.NET works (since it's the building block for most relational database code in .NET), it's better to use an abstraction. You end up writing less boilerplate. More concise, easier to read and refactor code. We often use Object Relational Mappers to accomplish this. There's two styles: Micro, and "full". There are several micro ORM's out there for .NET: Dapper, Npoco, PetaPoco etc. Stack Overflow (the website) uses Dapper. Then there's full ORM's such as Entity Framework and NHibernate.

You're using DataSet and DataTable. Those are poor abstractions. They don't follow Object Oriented Programming principles very well, they're too flexible, and they're inefficient. It's better to create custom classes and then use some form of ORM to map from your code to your custom classes.

You're also doing data access directly in your Web Forms. That's never a good idea. Database access should be done in a separate layer. That makes it easier to swap out either the data layer or the presentation layer, and makes it easier to re-use your data access code throughout other parts of your presentation layer.

Keeping all this in mind, we might end up with something like below. I chose Dapper. And I assumed Web Forms, but I think you'll get the idea no matter what your presentation layer is:

Data Repository

```
public class MySqlFilmRepository : IFilmRepository
{
    readonly string _connectionString { get; set; }

    public FilmRepsitory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Film> SearchFilmsByTitle(string title)
    {
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            List<Film> films = connection.Query<Film>("SELECT title, description, release_year, rental_rate, length, rating FROM film WHERE title LIKE @Title", new { Title = title }).AsList();

            return films;
        }
    }

    public List<Actor> GetActorsForFilm(string filmTitle)
    {
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            List<Actor> actors = connection.Query<Actor>("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM actor INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id INNER JOIN film ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id WHERE film.title LIKE @FilmTitle", new { FilmTitle = filmTitle }).AsList();

            return actors;
        }
    }
}

public interface IFilmRepository
{
    List<Film> SearchFilmsByTitle(string title);

    List<Actor> GetActorsForFilm(string filmTitle);
}
```

Model classes

```
public class Film
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }

    public decimal RentalRate { get; set; }

    public int Length { get; set; }

    public string Rating { get; set; }
}

public class Actor
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Web Forms code:

```
IFilmRepository _filmRepository;

public void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _filmRepository = new MySqlFilmRepository(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
}

protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = _filmRepository.SearchFilmsByTitle(SearchTextBox.Text);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = _filmRepository.GetActorsForFilm(SearchTextBox.Text);
}
```

It ends up being more code, but now you have a centralized place to get your data calls, and you're handling your connections properly, and you have less boilerplate code to query your database, and it's more flexible. This is more code, but it's also not really repeating itself very much.